# Live update textblock

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out the best way to have a text field live update between two different users.  I have done some googling and what I could find was the setInterval.

That works but is really straight forward and seems like the "wrong" way.  I don't know why it seems like that but I feel like there would be a more efficient way than having a setInterval update every 100ms or so.

Is there a better way than using setInterval? What is the best to update between two users?
Thanks for the help or pointing me in the right direction.

Edit --

Here is how I invision it
[Path of data http://img.zobgib.com/2011-03-23_2231.png](http://img.zobgib.com/2011-03-23_2231.png)

The information can also travel from comp 2 -> 1  of course so it is collaborative.

Comment: You mean two different users on two different computers?

Comment: @alex Yeah two different users on two different computers. And @JohnOpincar sorry I am a little fried from a long day I edited my question.

Comment: @alex php for the server side language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a *long polling* for example in PHP like so....

```
set_time_limit(0);

while (TRUE) {

  $results = Db::query('SELECT `message` FROM `messages` WHERE `modified` > :modified', array(':modified' => $modified));

  if ($results) {
     echo json_encode($results);
     exit;
  }

  sleep(5);

}
```

Assuming you are storing the state in a database.

#### Note

This is just scraping the surface of long polling, please conduct your own extensive research on it first including server configuration.

Comment: I understand this process just fine it is how you call that php file.  Should you use a setInterval with Ajax or is there a better way to make it more "live"

Comment: @zobgib Request it normally with XHR, and on return of new data, request it again (so wrap the call in a named function).

Answer (score 1):

open a comet connection to each user (reverse ajax, google it).  Then whenever the user changes something:

UserA-->Ajax-->Server-->Comet-->UserB

Answer (score 1):

If your not fearing HTML5 and both using HTML5 compatible browsers, you could build up a websocket server with php (phpwebsocket). Using it in a project and it IS the future :)

Comment: I am not afraid of html5 at all and this is a much better answer than the one I got above. If you can just put some resources in or give an example I am willing to change my accepted answer.